# Fastest way to format an integer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, formatting

There is a random number (not necessarily positive or integer), say, `-14383040.327843`. I want to turn it into `"(14,383,040)"`. So to spell it:

- negative number has to be in brackets
- fraction part should be stripped off without rounding
- every N decimal places (3 by default) from right to left there has to be a separator (`,` by default)
- no leading zeros

What is the fastest (across major browsers) way to get such string?

Comment: @epascarello `value < 0 ? '(' + String(value.toFixed(0)).split('').reverse().chunk(3).map(function(chunk) { return chunk.reverse().join(''); }).join(',') + ')' : String(value.toFixed(0)).split('').reverse().chunk(3).map(function(chunk) { return chunk.reverse().join(''); }).join(',')`

Comment: Probably not fast, just tried it out `"-231423421342134.327843".split(".")[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",").replace(/^-(.+)/,"($1)");`

Answer (score 1):

```
(Math.round(-14383040.327843)).toLocaleString();


/*  returned value: (String)
-14,383,040
*/
```

This value is returned in IE8 and IE10, Firefox 33,Opera 25 and Chrome 38.

To replace the minus-hyphen with parens-

```
(Math.round(-14383040.327843)).toLocaleString().replace(/\-(.+)/,'($1)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
x=-14383040.327843;
xf=Math.abs(x|0).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
xp=(x>0)?xf:"("+xf+")";
```

x is your variable, xf is formatted, and xp is for printing.